# Webcomic featuring a caveman mad scientist

Tags: story-identification, webcomics

I read this webcomic around 2005-2008-ish. The main comic was about mad scientist high school or college kids while at school. Main character had blonde hair and went around in a popped collar lab coat with butyl gloves and boots. The comic was fun and funny, decent artwork, although plenty of times the artwork would be rushed out and you could still see the blue pencil, or even just blue pencil.

Occasionally there would be a comic outside of the main storyline as a history of mad science. The one I remember is a caveman press conference, in two or three panels:

Panel 1: “Krog here to announce new invention. Krog invent wheel!”
Audience: “Groot invent wheel last week.”

Panel 2: “ah, but Krog invent wheel...with corners!”
Krog displays a large square wheel.

Panel 3: (from audience) “Krog mad fool!” “Krog meddle with things Krog no understand!”

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The webcomic is [*MAD About U*](http://madaboutu.keenspot.com). by Teague Tysseling. It takes place at a university for mad scientists. The main character, with the outfit you describe, is Galileo Von Frankenstien.

Krog introduces his [square wheel](http://madaboutu.keenspot.com/d/20050405.html) in a history lesson from Professor Wells.

[image: prehistoric man presenting the wheel with corners]

Comment: Thank you so much, that is indeed the one!

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you're looking for [Dresden Codak](http://dresdencodak.com/).

The Caveman Science Fiction comic you're referring to is [here](http://dresdencodak.com/2009/09/22/caveman-science-fiction/).

Comment: Sorry, I see the similarities in the caveman scientist but this is not the comic.

Comment: Me am play gods...